# Nonabelian Poincare duality

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, higher-algebra

Nonabelian Poincare duality is introduced by Jacob Lurie in ["Higher Algebra"](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/HA.pdf), Section 5.5.6.
It seems, that my question is closely related to this definition.

**Question**: what can one say about the functor $X\mapsto \Sigma^\infty Map(M,X)$ from spaces to spectra, if one knows, that $M$ is a compact closed oriented manifold?

By [Greg Arone, "A generalization of Snaith-type filtration"](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1999-351-03/S0002-9947-99-02405-8/S0002-9947-99-02405-8.pdf), for a parallelizable $M$ derivatives of this functor are quite specific.

Comment: It may be easier to answer the question if you make it a little more specific. I would say that the derivatives of this functor are described quite explicitly for any manifold $M$, and even more generally if $M$ is a finite CW complex. Namely, the $n$-th derivative is the Spanier-Whitehead dual of the suspension spectrum $\Sigma^\infty M^n/\Delta^nM$, where $\Delta^nM$ is the fat diagonal. I suspect you know this. What is it that you want to know?

Comment: To add to Greg's comment ... his paper tells you not only the derivatives, but how they are put together.  I suggest using MathSciNet to explore the many ways that his paper has been used.